# Can't deploy due to Postgress repo change

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

For the past day or so I cannot deploy my app (Rails) due to the repo for Postgress being removed:

```
E: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt trusty-pgdg Release' no longer has a Release file.
```

This is due to the trusty disto being EOLed, it seems (see  https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/YBMtd6nRuXyU2zS4%40msg.df7cb.de)

That's fine as if I was the admin of my system I could change the apt package, but this is Heroku. How can I get this updated? Can I, or do I have to hope the fine folks at Heroku fix this?